# main cell moves others will follow

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a cell and other cells show info from that cell and now i need to move the main cell. how can the other cells follow the main cell?
thanks

[image]

Comment: If you just insert four rows above the main cell, all of the formulas will adjust themselves.  That's not VBA, that's just Excel.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: the pic was an example. what I really do is update dates (main cell) and calculate how long each part of work will take.

so, if a change a date (main cell) and sort the date from old to new, the main cell may move, but the calculations won't!! i need them to know that they are linked to the date (main cell)

Comment: Ahhh.  Well, you can use a formula in columns C to F that will always refer to the cell in column a of the same row.  Then, if you sort column A, the formulae will recalculate based on the new value in that row.  Does that work for you?  (C8.formula  = "=A8 * 42")

Comment: i kind got what you meant. ok cool. thanks!